# OpenLayers 3, hover (select interaction with pointMove condition) on overlapping features

Tags: openlayers

It is not recommended to have multiple select interactions in Openlayers. I can create a hover interaction using the select function with the pointMove condition to highlight features and display a popup if required. The interaction targets multiple layers and the styling is defined by the source of the feature. The problem which I am having is with overlapping features. In particular with lines and points from separate layers which intersect polygon features.

If for example I run with cursor along a line into a polygon the line stays highlighted as expected. The same is true if I highlight a polygon but then want to highlight a point inside the polygon or a line which crosses the polygon. This seems to be impossible with the current library. The pointer condition is still true for the polygon geometry but I would like to assign an index to the other overlays with point or line features to highlight these features if the pointerMove condition validates.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/6ysd6s2q/) to show the issue.

Comment: Do you really need one layer for feature?

Comment: No the features could be all on the same layer, but that doesn't change the behavior. Once the polygon item is selected and in the foreground the pointMove condition will never evaluate for an underlying feature.

Comment: I'm doing some tests here.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/139942/50718)?

Comment: Get an idea there... I guess I need to build something around the forEachFeatureAtPixel event. Should be able to solve this and post an updated jsFiddle later today. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you're yet interested but I came up with [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zbqKeJ4lXQ8C60TC4fza?p=preview). I've learnt a lot doing this.

It looks like yours but I didn't remove `ol.interaction.Select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I like that solution. That you have both items selected and then only one item as you move into the selection is exactly the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. It was a good challenge!

Comment: @ads I'm not sure what is your case, I guess it's better if you create your own question.

Comment: Hover interaction will kill your performance unless you've got very few features.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I solved this selection quagmire by looking at forEachFeatureAtPixel in the pointermove event of the map object and add these to FeatureOverlay.

```
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#0d47a1',
      width: 2}),
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5.5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color:'#0d47a1',
          width:2
          })
        })
      })
    });

map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
  featureOverlay.getFeatures().clear();
  features = [];
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
    features.push(feature);
    });
  features.forEach(function(f){
    featureOverlay.addFeature(f);
    });
  });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/x4gdxweo/) is the forked jsFiddle.

Comment: this is how the earthquake example works too